# Why does ByteArrayOutputStream use int?

Tags: java

Maybe someone can help me understand because I feel I'm missing something that will likely have an effect on how my program runs.

I'm using a ByteArrayOutputStream. Unless I've missed something huge, the point of this class is to create a byte[] array for some other use.

However, the "plain" write function on BAOS takes an int not a byte ([ByteArrayOutputStream.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write%28int%29)).

According to this([Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)) page, in Java, an int is a 32-bit data type and a byte is an 8-bit data type.

If I write this code...

```
int i = 32;
byte b = i;
```

I get a warning about possible lossy conversions requiring a change to this...

```
int i = 32;
byte b = (byte)i;
```

I'm really confused about write(int)...

Comment: Note that it's `OutputStream.write` that determines this, not really `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Yep ByteArrayOutputStream is pretty much constrained to do it however its parent class does it.

Comment: It is arguably a bad idea to use the `byte` data type except in the form of `byte[]`. The same holds for `short`, IMHO. Think of byte and short as a necessary evil, that is only good for letting you read and write strange binary data formats. Don't use byte/short variables, method arguments or return types. (No, you won't save space in any substantial way (except in rare cirsumstances), and your code could actually be slower.)

Comment: Thanks for all the discussion. I WAS curious as to the motivation and the avoidance of casting many other functions does make sense, even if it niggles at my brain. I'm using the BAOS to generate custom bytecode for my own internal VM, so I also wanted to confirm that I wasn't writing something inherently broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ByteArrayOutputStream` is just overriding the abstract method declared in `OutputStream`. So the real question is why [`OutputStream.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) is declared that way, when its stated goal is to write a single byte to the stream. The implementation of the stream is irrelevant here.

Your intuition is correct - it's a broken bit of design, in my view. And yes, it will lose data, as is explicitly called out in the docs:

> The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

It would have been much more sensible (in my view) for this to be `write(byte)`. The only downside is that you couldn't then call it with literal values without casting:

```
// Write a single byte 0. Works with current code, wouldn't work if the parameter
// were byte.
stream.write(0);
```

That looks okay, but isn't - because the type of the literal 0 is `int`, which isn't implicitly convertible to `byte`. You'd have to use:

```
// Ugly, but would have been okay with write(byte).
stream.write((byte) 0);
```

For me that's not a good enough reason to design the API the way it is, but that's what we've got - and have had since Java 1.0. It can't be fixed now without it being a breaking change all over the place, unfortunately.

Comment: Bytes in Java are signed, so if the method took `byte` as an argument, we couldn't do `stream.write( 0xFF )` and get the expected all-on byte.  Now why java doesn't support an unsigned byte…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Java actually does support interpreting integer types up to int as unsigned, and to some extent even unsigned long. It was an extremely wise decision not to support that stuff explicitly. He who really needs unsigned (which is astonishing rare) will have to study the bit and shift operators a bit. So what?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: You'd be able to do `stream.write((byte) 0xff)` and the right thing would happen.

Comment: @Ingo I was mostly responding to "It would have been much more sensible (in my view) for this to be write(byte)."  If the method were `write(byte)`, then one would _have_ to use the advanced techniques that you describe in order to get the particular bit patterns in a `byte` that they want.

Comment: @Ingo: No, I would say it was a really bad idea to make `byte` signed. It's almost *always* more useful for it to be unsigned. (C# has both `byte` and `sbyte`, and I can't remember the last time I used `sbyte`.) See also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/bloch-effective-08-qa-140880.html

Comment: Oh, you're right, the casting works.  This is interesting because `byte b = 255;` won't compile, saying "cannot convert from int to byte", but of course, `byte b = (byte) 255` works.  Casting works, but the direct conversion doesn't. My mistake. I agree that it would be useful to have an unsigned byte type, and that was the point I was trying to make (but I made a mistake).

Comment: @JonSkeet You're certainly right that we all want `byte` to be unsigned. But the Java designers have a point insofar that they wanted consistent numeric integral types, which is in itself a noble idea. I am sure, if they had foreseen the confusion that would arise  from that decision they had decided otherwise.

Comment: @Ingo: The problem is regarding `byte` as a numeric type to start with. In my experience it's usually used for values which aren't really handled as plain numbers to start with - just like `char` values aren't. (Yes, you can do the same operations with them, but they're usually not representing some sort of magnitude.) `char` is unsigned, so why shouldn't `byte` be?

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, the idea that byte be numeric was wrong - at least from the POV today, where Java is more a server language, rather than one that controls washing machines ... where having small signed numbers probably did make sense in the 90ties.

Answer (score 6):

In order to facilitate unsigned bytes above `0x7F` this takes place. The int will be silently narrowed to be written. In fact, the code [does that](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java#ByteArrayOutputStream.write%28int%29) with a `(byte)` cast.

As Ingo states:

> A possible reason could be that the byte to write will most often be the result of some operation that automatically converts its operands to int[, like] some bit operations. Hence, the code would be littered with casts to byte, that add nothing to understanding.

Comment: It's not at all clear why it couldn't have been a `byte` parameter though - the caller could easily have cast if they wanted to...

Comment: @JonSkeet Many design decisions in Java APIs are such that it is difficult to find a rational reason behind them. The fact of the matter is that the method takes an int and does an explicit cast within.

Comment: That's the fact of the *what* - but the question asks *why*. I agree it's hard to find a reason here - but that just means we don't know the answer to the question that was asked...

Comment: @JonSkeet I personally don't see/assume a "why" in there(though it is really a matter of interpretation). The OP just states that they are confused, and in my opinion this explains the "what" that answers their confusion. They simply want it to work at this point.

Comment: Does the title not give it away? "Why does ByteArrayOutputStream use int?"

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, right. I have an issue of never looking at titles, and I often automatically take the body as the more concrete definition of an inquiry.

Comment: A possible reason could be that the byte to write will most often be the result of some operation that automatically converts its operands to `int`. Like some bit operations. Hence, the code would be littered with casts to `byte`, that add nothing to understanding. Arguably, if Java would be invented today, it would be a good idea to allow byte and short only when followed by [], and keep all method signatures clean of byte and short.

Comment: @Ingo: I'd say it *does* make the code clearer, because it makes it obvious that you're only writing a single byte rather than the whole integer. If you've got a calculation which results in an `int`, and you call `write(value)` it's not immediately obvious that three-quarters of the potential data is going to be removed...

Comment: It depends, @JonSkeet. If you have `byte[] src = ...; write(src[5] ^ 0x40)` it looks perfectly fine, and many won't even notice that the argument expression is actually an `int`.

Comment: @Ingo: I'd say that's an indication that bitwise operations on bytes ought to be handled smarter in general, to be honest. (There are various language changes which would make all kinds of things nicer around this area.)

Answer (score 0):

That's mostly because **the Java Virtual Machine model's stack hates `byte`, but loves `int`.** The stack uses 32-bit slots , which matches the size of an `int`.

You will notice however that **java *does* like `byte[]` references**. But that's because the content of arrays is stored in the heap (not the stack). And whenever a specific `byte` is addressed and moved to the stack (the `bipush` or `sipush` opcodes) then they are immediately converted to integers.

But sometimes java actually uses **257(!)** values. When an `InputStream#read()` returns 256 values, but when it has no content it will return a `-1` value. Alternatively, it would have been possible to throw an `EOFException` (like some other methods do) but exceptions are slow in java.

Even though you don't need the `-1` value for the `OutputStream#write` **it's coherent, and it reduces casting. But yes, it's missleading too.**