# Unclear use of int variable - official Oracle example Using Byte Streams

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I started to learn about Streams, and I encountered this site:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

They have example about using `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.

What I want to know is, why do we use variable `int c` instead of `char c`, especially when we know that `int` is 4B long, and char is 1B long.
**How do methods `read()` and `write()` "know" that they should read and write character?**

Here is the code originally posted on page above:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: char is not 1 byte long, BTW. It's 2 bytes long. And streams don't read and write characters. They read and write bytes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439695/why-does-bytearrayoutputstream-use-int for a discussion of `write(int)`